# How to replace rrpmrc file functionality in rpm 5.1.6

Tags: build-process, packaging, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

In my project I use --rcfile option for rpmbuild settings ... however with new rpm version (5.1.6) this option is not available ... how can I replace the rpmrc file with the new version .. Any doc for help ?

Answer (score 0):

There was [this post](http://rpm5.org/community/popt-devel/0262.html) from the mailing list that explains some options for getting around the removal of the --rcfile command.

Answer (score 0):

Set %optflags in a file and use --macros to point to the file is the replacement for --rcfile. You can use a macro like %{target_cpu} in the path if you wish to have multiple arches supported by a single --macros invocation.